# Opening a new window check if the attribute is in the new window with the page

Tags: javascript, html

I need help, I want code to do something like that
Open a new window, check if the attribute is in a new window with the page.
Check if the element is in the second window and return the information to the first one

```html
<body>
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked>Regulamin</label>
<br>
<button onclick="openWindow()">Otwiera okno 1</button>
<br>
<button onclick="element()">Sprawdz element</button>
<br>
<button onclick="wykrywanie()">Sprawdz wykrywanie w oknie </button>  
<script>
function openWindow(){
    var win = window.open('https://www.wp.pl/', '1366002941508',  'width=700,height=500,left=375,top=330');
    setTimeout(function(){
        win.close()
    }, 3000);
    return false;
}
function element(){
 if ($("input").is(':checked')) {
 alert('kliknięto w like');
 } else{ alert('nie klik w like');
}
}
function wykrywanie(){
    var newWindow = window.open('https://www.wp.pl/', '1366002941508',  'width=700,height=500,left=375,top=330');
newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "<b>mateusztoja</b>";
newWindow.document.close();
    return false;
 } 
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You cannot access a new window content from a different origin. You cannot document.body.innerHTML to a new window from a different origin. You can document.write to a new window you opened without a URL

Comment: Maybe Selenium could be useful for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Can I download a specific trial code from window 2 (open)? then check it on your website or does it contain the attribute?

Answer (score -1):

1. If you are trying to open page with other domain:

   You can't access to others domains windows/page html via javascript. You can get html from server side using some think like ..GetResponse..
2. It's better to use e.g. jQuery dialog instead of `window.open-dialog` (https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) for interactions on same domains

Comment: Can I download a specific trial code from window 2 (open)? then check it on your website or does it contain the attribute?

Comment: Can I download a specific trial code from window 2 (open)?